# Pass a parameter value starting with minus (-) using argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm doing a command line utility that can receive a parameter starting with a minus or plus, for instance, *-gtest* or *+gtest* the problem is that python3 don't accept this:

This is a minimal code that reproduce this problem:
import argparse

```
if (__name__== "__main__"):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--string', action='store',
                        help='String value')
    p = parser.parse_args()
    if p.string:
        print("pass value:", p.string)
```

I try to invoke it as:

```
./example.py -s -gtest
./example.py -s "-gtest"
./example.py -s \-gtest
```

And always get next error:

```
usage: example.py [-h] [-s STRING]
example.py: error: argument -s/--string: expected one argument
```

So, my question is how I can pass a argument starting with a minus using argparse

Comment: `--string="-gtest"` works, see the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks!, I miss this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run it with:

```
python example.py -s-gtest
python example.py -s+gtest
```

So simply not putting any space, nor escaping it in any special way.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, that is exactly was I was looking for!